# Extra spacing when pasting into MS Word

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I'm using ZeroClipboard to copy data from a web page to the clipboard. Some processing is done on it like converting `<br/>` tags to end of line characters. When the users copy and paste it into WordPad, the spacing is fine. When they do it in Word 2007 or 2010, there is an extra 10 points of space between each line.

My question is, is this something my code is doing or something that MS Word is doing? I'm applying only `\n` not `\r\n` as the end of line characters, but even applying the latter did not seem to change anything for the better.

Comment: My bet is that it's word - they add a space after each paragraph, unless you turn that off.

Comment: After-lunch follow-up: check Home->Paragraph->Line and Paragraph Spacing (it's the icon with an up and down arrow by some text lines).  If there's an option to "Remove Space After Paragraph", then the option to add a space after each paragraph is currently turned on.